# Weird behavior with parse_url and different protocols

Tags: php

I am trying to use `parse_url` to decode a DSN and found a weird behavior.
Here are the sample DSNs:

```
parse_url('redis://localhost'); //Correctly parses
parse_url('file:///var/sessions'); //Correctly parses
parse_url('redis:///var/run/redis.sock'); //Parse error
parse_url('file:///var/run/redis.sock'); //Correctly parses
```

It seems that it fail to parse urls without a host, but makes an exception for `file` scheme.
Am I missing something?
Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Those are not supported by `parse_url`, `function is intended specifically for the purpose of parsing URLs and not URIs`

Answer (score 2):

The manual of [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) mention that you cannot use this function for URIs. Specifically, when you have triple slashes for the scheme, it is defined as "invalid" and this function returns `false`:

> **Note:**
>
> This function is intended specifically for the purpose of parsing URLs and not URIs. However, to comply with PHP's backwards compatibility requirements it makes an exception for the file:// scheme where triple slashes (file:///...) are allowed. For any other scheme this is invalid.

Comment: Is there a way to parse URI (setting enabling it for `parse_url` or a different php function), or do I need to implement all the logic myself?